# How to deploy automatically Azure VMs and AKS on an environment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I made a Terraform to create an infrastructure on Azure.
I used the provider "microsoft/azuredevops".

I need to add VMs and Azure Kubernetes Service on a specific environment that I created.
My question is how to deploy the script (which put tags) to them ?

It's not possible to deploy it in an Azure DevOps Pipeline because this last doesn't know VMs (and AKS).
I don't see anything else to made it with the provider azuredevops.

The solution (I think) will would be to extract the original script from an environment on Pipeline/Environment. I need to change all variables as personal access token and others too.
But I don't know if Microsoft change the script regularly.

What's the best solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage Azure resources with Terraform then you need to use the [AzureRM provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) not the Azure DevOps provider. The Azure DevOps provider is for managing your Azure DevOps instance.

The AzureRM provider contains resources for managing [Linux](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine) and [Windows](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine) VM's or for other types of resource such as [AKS](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster)

Once you've written your terraform code, you can use a pipeline to run the terraform against Azure. Microsoft provide a [terraform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks) which can be used to call terraform in your pipeline

For the pipeline to be able to authenticate against Azure you'll need to set up a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops). This will allow the pipeline to use a service principle in azure which can be given the appropriate level of permissions to create, update, destroy Azure Resources

Hashicorp have a good [tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/azure-get-started) on getting started with Terraform and Azure and Microsoft also have some good [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/)

Microsoft also have a [tutorial](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/) on using Terraform from a pipeline, it uses the classic GUI based pipelines rather than YAML but the tasks and principles will be the same for both

Comment: Hello,

I find that it's not possible to automate all I need on Azure DevOps with this plugin.

Comment: You can automate pretty much everything using the AureRM provider, even if the resource doesn't explicitly exist, because it's new, you can call the Azure API Directly. Can you give an example of what you want to Automate that isn't supported?

Comment: Sure. I need to deploy the azure agent (from a specific azure devops environment) on each linux and windows virtual machine. I need the same for azure kubernetes services.

Comment: OK terraform isn't going to help you do that. It will help you provision a VM / AKS instance, but once you want to do things inside the VM / container then you need to look at other tools. For VM's you should look at remoting and running a script that runs the agent installer. For windows you probably want to look at WinRM + Powershell and for linux SSH + Bash. For AKS you don't need to run an agent on K8's you can just use standard build agent to run the K8's tasks and use the built in functionality of Azure DevOps environments to manage deployments to specific namespaces

Comment: Yes. At the beginning, I think to use Ansible because I will use it to configure all virtual machines. Another solution is to use azurerm_virtual_machine_extension. This will probably work but there is a personal access token on each script and a specific version for the vsts agent. I think I can variable the PAT. How to detect when the vsts agent version will change ?